# $\frac{\alpha+k-1}{k}$ is the minumum probability that verifies a condition for finite covers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

Prove that $\frac{\alpha+k-1}{k}$ is the minumum $p\in(0,1]$ such that for every probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ and $\forall\{U_{1},...,U_{k}\}$ $\subseteq$ $\Sigma-\{\emptyset\}$ $∣$ $\Omega=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k}U_{i}$ $ $ $\land$ $ $ $p\le\mathbb{P}(U_{i})$ $\forall$$i\in\{1,...,k\}$, you have $\alpha\le\mathbb{P}(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{k}U_{i})$.

***EDIT:*** $ $ @AlbertParadek proves in his answer that the statement as it was written (see edit history) was false. The new one is true: the bound can be found by De Morgan's Law and union bound, and that it is minimum can be proven using the counting measure in a finite probability space.

Comment: I proved that $\frac{\alpha+k-1}{k}$ verifies the given condition. Then I tried to show that it is indeed the minimum by induction, because clearly for $k=1$, $p=\alpha$, and it is trivially true, but I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: I don't think it holds in general. Let $\Sigma=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ be a trivial sigma-algebra. Then, any $p>0$ fulfills the condition, because if $P(U_i)\geq p$ then necessary $U_i=\Omega$ and trivially $\alpha\leq P(\Omega)$.  It can be an interesting question to consider e.g. on real line with borel sigma algebra though.

Comment: Also, you probably want $U_i\in\Sigma$ and not $U_i\subseteq\Sigma$.

Comment: @AlbertParadek you are right in the first comment, check edit, but you are wrong in the second, I had written what you say. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that $\frac{\alpha+k-1}{k}$ is the correct result though. Denote $U=\cap_{i=1}^k U_i$. Take (if possible) $P(U_i)=p$ such that $U_i\cap U_j=U$, which means that all of them contain $U$ but otherwise are disjoint. Then, by inclusion-exclusion principle, we have

$$
1=P(\cup U_i) = \sum_{i=1}^k P(U_i) - \sum_{i\neq j} P(U_i\cap U_j) + \sum_{i\neq j\neq l} P(U_i\cap U_j\cap U_l)\dots \pm P(U). 
$$

By assumptions, all $P(U_i\cap U_j)=P(U_i\cap U_j\cap U_l)=\dots =P(U)=\alpha$ and $P(U_i)=p$.  All put together we get

$$
1=kp + \alpha ( -\binom{k}{2} + \binom{k}{3}\dots \pm \binom{k}{k})=kp+\alpha (k-1).  
$$
Therefore **$p=\frac{1+\alpha(k-1)}{k}$**$<\frac{\alpha+k-1}{k}$.

Note a few things: it may be not possible to take such appropriate $U_i$ and I dont think we can say something at all in general (without at least some knowledge of $\Sigma$). On the other hand, I dont think that (for any $\Sigma$) we can obtain lower number than $\frac{1+\alpha(k-1)}{k}$. This is evident from the construction of the inclusion-exclusion sum. If some of them have some common intersection besides $U$, then the right hand side would be larger.

Comment: You are completly right. This is a mistake of mine traying to make a big generalisation and abstraction of a more concrete problem. The correct problem is: prove that $\frac{\alpha+k-1}{k}$ is the minimun $p\in[0,1]$ that verifies the condition for EVERY probability space.

Comment: Should I delete the answer or just edit it? If the latter the problem is that this answer will make no sense.

Comment: Yes, a problem formulated like that makes perfect sense.

Comment: I still dont get it though. $\frac{\alpha+k-1}{k}$ is still not a correct answer, because I found a ppty space for which we need smaller $p$ than this (if I didn't make a mistake).

Comment: just edit the problem in such a case I think

Comment: and will you edit your answer too? Is that I don't want to bellitle your work in this answer.

Comment:  dont worry about that.

Comment: Done. Thank you. I let you write (if you want) the new correct answer.